# Python file with out close

Tags: python, python-3.x, garbage-collection

If I write code like this, What will happen? Will the file object close automatically?

```
# Do something before
# Make the value = 1 when the number in file.
for line in open('input_file.txt', 'r'):
    index_list[int(line)] = 1
# Do something later
```

Or I have to write code like this?

```
with open('xxx.txt', 'r') as f:
    # Do something
```

Comment: 1) No, it won't. 2) You should since using the `with` statement with `file` objects calls it's `.close` method for you behind the scenes (i.e automatically).

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard In this first case as the file object doesn't have any references after the loop, hence it will get deallocated automatically and in turn calling [its close method](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/fileobject.c#l612). Unless of course there's an exception, which is why `with` statement is always better.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary As far as I know, the language gaurantees no such thing, so it can vary wildly by implementation. And even in CPython, which does this, it depends a lot on when the object is actually garbage-collected, potentially leaving the file open longer than expected. So yeah, don't count on it...